# Execute a SQL file inside PHP script with exec, sql results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, output, exec

So i am executing a SQL file inside a php script, the commands i am using are :

```
$commande = 'mysql --host='.BDD_HOST.' --user='.BDD_USER.' --password='.BDD_PASSWORD.' --database='.BDD_DATABASE.' --execute="SOURCE '.$file_path.'"';

exec($commande,$output,$retval);
```

And to test if the file is executed i check if retval = 0, my problem is this test only make sure that the exec has been executed without checkking if the sql doesn't have any bugs or if the queries inside are working. I need to find a way to test the content of the sql file
Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: And what does `$output` say? _If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command._ I suppose if there's something wrong mysql will report it.

Comment: @Michel output is an empty array that returns ntg